# Unable to Load Dependent on Multi-Select using PHP and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I tried to load state list multiple selected country and it worked when i tried form here https://phppot.com/php/load-dependent-dropdown-on-multi-select-using-php-and-jquery/

i tried to make some little change by replacing `<select>` with `<input type="checkbox">`

but it doesn't load any state list and i get error in console

```
 index.php:36 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
at getState (index.php:36)
at HTMLInputElement.onchange (index.php:64)
 getState @ index.php:36
 onchange @ index.php:64
```

**HERE IS WHAT I TRIED:**

```
<div class="row">
  <label>Country:</label><br /> 
     <?php
         foreach ($countryResult as $country) {
     ?>
          <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="country[]" id="<?php echo $country["id"]; ?>" onChange="getState();" value="<?php echo $country["id"]; ?>">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="<?php echo $country["id"]; ?>">
                            <?php echo $country["country_name"]; ?>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label>State:</label>
            <select name="state[]" id="state-list" class="demoInputBox" multiple size=5>
                <option value="">Select State</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
function getState() {
            var str = '';
            var val = document.getElementById('country-list');
            for (i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
                if (val[i].selected) {
                    str += val[i].value + ',';
                }
            }
            var str = str.slice(0, str.length - 1);

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "get_state.php",
                data: 'country_id=' + str,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#state-list").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

**GET_STATE.PHP**

```
<?php
  require_once("DBController.php");
  $db_handle = new DBController();
   if(!empty($_GET['country_id'])) {
    $coun_id = $_GET["country_id"];           
    $query ="SELECT * FROM states WHERE countryID IN ($coun_id)";
  $results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
  ?>
    <option value="">Select State</option>
 <?php
    foreach($results as $state) {
 ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $state["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $state["name"]; ?></option>
<?php
 }
}
?>
```

**HOW DO I LOAD DATA WITH CHECKBOX INSTEAD OF `<select>`**

Comment: where is your country-list id and why are you using two value in input type checkbox

Comment: @NurbekBoymurodov check my question i made changes

Comment: where is your id which country-list

Comment: you are writing on id country id

Comment: @NurbekBoymurodov can you please help me with that, if its a `<select>` i can point to specific `ID` but how do i do with `checkbox`, since checkbox has its own unique `id`

Comment: can you use jquery there are easier way in jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this   maybe it helps you

```
<div class="row">
  <label>Country:</label><br /> 
     <?php
         foreach ($countryResult as $country) {
     ?>
          <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input country-list" type="checkbox" name="country[]"  onChange="getState();" value="<?php echo $country["id"]; ?>">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="<?php echo $country["id"]; ?>">
                            <?php echo $country["country_name"]; ?>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label>State:</label>
            <select name="state[]" id="state-list" class="demoInputBox" multiple size=5>
                <option value="">Select State</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Script

```
function getState() {
            var str = '';
            var val = document.getElementsByClassName('country-list');
            for (i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
                if (val[i].checked) {
                    str += val[i].value + ',';
                }
            }
            var str = str.slice(0, str.length - 1);

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "get_state.php",
                data: 'country_id=' + str,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#state-list").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: i get following error `document.getElementByClassName is not a function`

Comment: can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58488920/unable-to-dynamically-load-dependent-checkbox-on-multi-select-checkbox-in-ajax