# Unable to Dynamically Load Dependent Checkbox on Multi-Select checkbox in AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Am trying to load country and state list based on selected country(Checkbox) and it can load selected country and its state to Checkbox,

but the problem in when i select two country it loads only one country state list doesn't loads first country when i select second.

**PROBLEM**

- when i select china and india, only india state list is generated.
- it generates the last selected country list.

**PHP**

```
require_once ("config.php");
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM country");
$query->execute();
$countryResult = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($countryResult as $country) {
?>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input country-list" type="checkbox" name="country[]"  onChange="getState();" value="<?php echo $country["id"]; ?>">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="<?php echo $country["id"]; ?>">
           <?php echo $country["country_name"]; ?>
    </label>
  </div>
<?php
    }
?>
<div class="row">
            <label>State:</label>
            <div id="state-list" class="demoInputBox">
            </div>
        </div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
function getState() {
            var str = '';
            var val = document.getElementsByClassName('country-list');
            for (i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
                if (val[i].checked) {
                    str += val[i].value + ',';
                }
            }
            var str = str.slice(0, str.length - 1);

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "get_state.php",
                data: 'country_id=' + str,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#state-list").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

**Get_state.php**

```
require_once("config.php");
if (!empty($_GET['country_id'])) {
    $coun_id = $_GET["country_id"];
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM states WHERE countryID=:coun_id");
    $query->bindParam(':coun_id', $coun_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
    $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    ?>
    <?php
    foreach ($results as $state) {
        ?>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input country-list" type="checkbox" name="state[]" onChange="getState();" value="<?php echo $state["id"]; ?>">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="<?php echo $state["name"]; ?>">
                <?php echo $state["name"]; ?>
            </label>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: There is one parameter in your query, there is no loop or something that shows a list of IDs in your PHP script

Comment: @KubiRoazhon where should i add loop..?

Comment: If you're getting a list of countries id in your php script you must change your query to something like `$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM states WHERE countryID in (id1,id2,id3) );`

Comment: @KubiRoazhon i tried this https://jsfiddle.net/z0rfjus8/ it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you check your ajax 
if it sending correct data then 
try this maybe it helps you

```
require_once("config.php");

if (!empty($_GET['country_id'])) {
    $coun_id = $_GET["country_id"];
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM states WHERE countryID IN ($coun_id)");
    $query->bindParam(':coun_id', $coun_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
    $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    ?>
    <?php
    foreach ($results as $state) {
        ?>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input country-list" type="checkbox" name="state[]" onChange="getState();" value="<?php echo $state["id"]; ?>">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="<?php echo $state["name"]; ?>">
                <?php echo $state["name"]; ?>
            </label>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: can you mention what mistakei made

Comment: you are compare string with country id in WHERE clause can you show me what data in getstate.php when you get post data with multiple state

Comment: You are using WHERE clause and it is working with single comparison WHERE IN clause is working with multiple comparison and it takes all cities where state id like (1, 3, and so on) so I mean WHERE  clause is your mistake

Comment: but when i try `WHERE countryID IN (:coun_id)");` it doesn't work